# Seleccionar todos los elementos <li> y convertir en <a href>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pues eso,

Tengo una lista `<li>` con elementos que se van creando de forma dinámica, siempre tienen esta estructura:

```
<li>TEXTO: url</li>
```

Donde `TEXTO:` nunca cambia, siempre es la misma palabra, y `URL` puede variar.

Había pensado con JS, buscar el string `TEXTO:` y reemplazarlo por `<a href="`

```js
var i = "TU SITIO:".replace('TU SITIO:','<a href="');
```

```html
<li>TU SITIO: https://example.com/100</li>
<li>TU SITIO: https://example.com/index.html/otros</li>
<li>TU SITIO: https://example.com/cambio.php</li>
```

No sé si sea lo correcto, o si existe un método más comodo, actualmente no uso jQuery, pero podría implementarlo. Si necesitan que corriga algo, con gusto esta´re atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Lo podrias hacer con un [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Pero si nos muestras tu codigo JavaScript te podriamos ayudar mejor

Comment: gracias @RicardoSanchez estuve leyendo, y no vi la forma clara de hacerlo con lo que me compartes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comparto una solución:

```js
const items = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const link = items[i].textContent.split('TU SITIO:')[1]
  const anchor = `TU SITIO: <a href=${link.trim()}>${link}</a>`
  items[i].innerHTML = anchor
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <li>TU SITIO: https://example.com/100</li>
  <li>TU SITIO: https://example.com/index.html/otros</li>
  <li>TU SITIO: https://example.com/cambio.php</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona. Aunque al crearse de forma dinamica, no está tomando como lo necestio, pero creo que eso da para otra pregunta. voy a seguir investigando y sino te comparto por acá

Comment: A su servicio @Alvamon6 saludos

Answer (score 2):

Esta seria una forma de hacerlo con jQuery

```
    $(function(){
        $('li').each(function(){
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = this.innerText.replace('TEXTO: ', '').trim();
            this.replaceWith(a);
        })
    })
```

Espero te ayude!

Comment: Gracias por su tiempo Jorge, agradecido